# {derivativeurn} - properties.db

Tags: powershell, sqlite, autodesk-model-derivative

i am using the [{urn}/manifest/{derivativeurn}](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/) to download the properties.db file, my steps are

1. use the method `HEAD` to collect the content length (approx 2gb)
2. use that content length to figure out the chuck sizes to collect the data in using the range header (approx 100mb)
3. collect the data in ranges 0-100,101-200,201-300... between each range i append the data to my .db file that is on my loacal drive `$data | Out-File -Encoding Ascii -Append "C:\Temp\sample.db"  -NoNewline`

the script runs fine and seems to collect all the data, when i try to then open it in DB Browser for SQLite i get the error[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeevk.png)

im not sure what is causing the error, can anyone advise on it please?

Comment: The logic describe above looks correct, but without seeing the code it is hard to tell what's wrong. As long, you manage gzip encoding in your request, that you assemble chunks properly it should work. I am suing the same technique in my sample with no problem.

Comment: I have sent it to forge help with code that i am using, I wonder if it's handling the GZip encoding

Comment: @cyrille , i dont see anything relating to the gzip in the documentation. am i missing something obvious?